# Find the intersection of two curves from SQL data

Tags: c#, t-sql, plot, intersection, curve

I have statistical data on a Microsoft SQL Server and would like to find the intersection of two curves from (x,y) data I query from the tables.  I have found some articles relating to doing this in excel, but I'm not sure how to proceed in SQL. How would I do this in either T-SQL or C# code?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't try doing this in SQL.  :)

Comment: How about starting by letting us know of how data is structured?

Comment: by intersection you mean finding a common point from both curves or fitting two curves on the (x,y) data and finding their intersection? The first is doable in SQL while the latter is (hopefully) not.

Answer (score 1):

To find the intersection of two curves you must isolate a variable on each equation, then set the two equations equal to each other and solve for the variable you isolated. SQL is definitely not my language of choice for this task.

Comment: The necessary formulas should first be derived (approximated) from the sets of (x,y) data the OP has got in their tables, from what I read.